# Não consigo instalar matplotlib, Python 3.9

Tags: python, matplotlib, pip

Começa ocorrendo normalmente e do nada, depois de algumas linhas, começa uma série de erros. Eu inclusive já atualizei o Visual Studio de todas as maneiras possíveis.

Segue o erro:

````
C:\Users\dborg>pip install matplotlib
Collecting matplotlib
  Using cached matplotlib-3.3.2.tar.gz (37.9 MB)
Collecting certifi>=2020.06.20
  Using cached certifi-2020.6.20-py2.py3-none-any.whl (156 kB)
Collecting cycler>=0.10
  Using cached cycler-0.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.5 kB)
Collecting kiwisolver>=1.0.1
  Using cached kiwisolver-1.2.0.tar.gz (52 kB)


```ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\dborg\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\dborg\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-gohi4t96\\kiwisolver\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\dborg\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-gohi4t96\\kiwisolver\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\dborg\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-66udtmkr'
         cwd: C:\Users\dborg\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gohi4t96\kiwisolver\
    Complete output (44 lines):
    WARNING: The wheel package is not available.
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: 'c:\users\dborg\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\dborg\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-wheel-g9dhur8h\\cppy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\dborg\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-wheel-g9dhur8h\\cppy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\dborg\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-axa804ph'
           cwd: C:\Users\dborg\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-g9dhur8h\cppy\
      Complete output (6 lines):
      usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
         or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
         or: setup.py --help-commands
         or: setup.py cmd --help

      error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'
      ----------------------------------------
      ERROR: Failed building wheel for cppy
    ERROR: Failed to build one or more wheels
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\users\dborg\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\installer.py", line 126, in fetch_build_egg
        subprocess.check_call(cmd)
      File "c:\users\dborg\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 373, in check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['c:\\users\\dborg\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\python.exe', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', 'C:\\Users\\dborg\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmp0kc5ptku', '--quiet', 'cppy>=1.1.0']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

    The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\dborg\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gohi4t96\kiwisolver\setup.py", line 59, in <module>
        setup(
      File "c:\users\dborg\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 152, in setup
        _install_setup_requires(attrs)
      File "c:\users\dborg\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 147, in _install_setup_requires
        dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
      File "c:\users\dborg\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 673, in fetch_build_eggs
        resolved_dists = pkg_resources.working_set.resolve(
      File "c:\users\dborg\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 764, in resolve
        dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(
      File "c:\users\dborg\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1049, in best_match
        return self.obtain(req, installer)
      File "c:\users\dborg\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1061, in obtain
        return installer(requirement)
      File "c:\users\dborg\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 732, in fetch_build_egg
        return fetch_build_egg(self, req)
      File "c:\users\dborg\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\installer.py", line 128, in fetch_build_egg
        raise DistutilsError(str(e)) from e
    distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Command '['c:\\users\\dborg\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\python.exe', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', 'C:\\Users\\dborg\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmp0kc5ptku', '--quiet', 'cppy>=1.1.0']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.```
````

Comment: Parece que não tem wheels do Matplotlib para o Python 3.0. Veja este [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64433348/matplotlib-not-found-in-python-3-9)

Comment: Consegui resolver com a resposta do Wellington Silva, então creio que agora já há.

Obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá, estava com mesmo problema que você, consegui sanar utilizando o arquivo binário do matplotlib, vide o comando:

```
pip install wheel \
python -m pip install -U matplotlib --prefer-binary
```

Caso tenha alguma dúvida consulte o endereço do stackoverflow em inglês[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64285251/problem-with-installation-of-matplotlib-in-python), no qual está a solução.

Comment: Consegui resolver desta maneira. Muito obrigado, me salvou!